# WooCommerce how to change chunks of text in the final html

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, replace, hook-woocommerce

I need to replace a chunk of text in a WooCommerce page right before it is sent to the browser.

I have tried the following code that I found on the web :

```
function start_modify_html() {
   ob_start();
}

function end_modify_html() {
   $html = ob_get_clean();
   $html = str_replace( 'old string', 'new string', $html );
   echo $html;
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'start_modify_html' );
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'end_modify_html' );
```

It works, but unless I am missing something, it only works in the body section of the page, and the text I need to replace is located in the header section.

What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly is the text you want to change? Please provide a screenshot or more details.

Comment: I need to change some css that are in the <head><style> section of the page, and more specifically a few colors such as #401200.

Comment: Have you thought about overwriting the elements with your new css codes instead of changing the css codes? Take a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp AND https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but I already tried some of them. I am no WP expert, but these css seem to be shortcodes-inline-css. However I was unable to find where or how they are generated. So my last & easiest option was to try to replace a chunk of text relative to a single color directly in the html output.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'start_custom_buffer', 9999);
add_action('shutdown', 'end_custom_buffer', 1);

function start_custom_buffer() {

    ob_start();
    ob_start('end_custom_buffer');
}

function end_custom_buffer($buffer = '') {
    $buffer = str_replace( 'Shop', 'Shopreplacedd', $buffer );
    return $buffer;
}
```

Start buffering on `teplate_redirect` hook and on `shutdown` (the website loading end), replace the desired strings and return the buffer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work...